# Layered and Role Based Taxonomy in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I want to achieve something like this:

- admin can create taxonomy. (already have)
- admin assign a taxonomy to specific vendor. (already have)
- vendor can create more taxonomy, with an extra field keeping track that the taxonomy belongs to that specific vendor.

Now i'm in the mist giving permission to vendor to edit taxonomy, and the logic behind. I have the following code in my includes/taxonomy.php in my plugin:

```
function WCPVPlus_register_taxonomy_args( $args, $taxonomy, $object_type ) {
    if(MY_TAXONOMY===$taxonomy){
        $args['capabilities'] =array(
            'manage_terms' => 'read',
            'edit_terms'   => 'read',
            'delete_terms' => 'read',
            'assign_terms' => 'read',
        );
    };
    return $args;
}
add_filter('register_taxonomy_args', 'WCPVPlus_register_taxonomy_args', 10, 3);
```

then in my main php file, i have this in the init method:

```
include_once('includes/taxonomy.php');
```

The code doesn't seem to work, as when i debug using xdebug, the code doesn't stop at WCPVPlus_register_taxonomy_args function.

Is there anyone here to explain the concept behind and enlighten me in achieving what i'm trying to do?